# How to request a server side variable from client with socket.io

Tags: reactjs, node.js, express, socket.io

I have a react app with node.js, express and am using socket.io.

I have stored a variable that stores a number to be displayed in the frontend, but I want the frontend to request it from the backend. I'm not sure how to do this though because as far as the docs go, it only shows how to emit something from the backend to the frontend, and not back and forth.

client:

```
socket.emit("join_random_result", (open) => {
  setOpenLobby(open);
});
```

server:

```
var open = 3;

socket.on("join_random_result", (open) => {
  socket.emit(???)
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially it’s a call back function being passed into the backend that you need.

```
1.  Frontend: Request the number using socket.emit("request_open_value");.
2.  Backend: On receiving the request, send back open with socket.emit("open_value", open);.
3.  Frontend: Update state by listening with socket.on("open_value", (value) => setOpenLobby(value));.
```

Comment: Is there a way to have my code pause until this whole call back is completed? I've added awaits to each of these socket calls but it still doesn't update my setOpenLobby in time

Comment: ^ Came up with a way past that issue, just made sure that I use the updated value I need INSIDE the useMemo() I'm listening for the callback in